# как в calendar material view выделить дни

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня есть массив где есть год, месяц и день

Comment: 1. Можно менять используемый шаблон.
2. Можно показывать скрытый по-дефолту круг.
3. Добавлять круг программно (не лучшая идея)

Comment: подскажете как сделать????